# How do I add custom elements to the div on the top of the datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery and the datatables library to render a datatable. My current set-up looks like this:

[image]

Currently the hide columns multi-selector, export data to csv button and the two inputs are in the body above the datatable, but I want them to be in the div right above the data table where the show entries selector and the search input are.

I followed [this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html) tutorial on the datatables website to add custom elements to the toolbar to get the idea of adding custom elements. But adding the div with the text removes the show entries selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add character `l` to the value of the `dom` option to show page length control as well.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"toolbar">lfrtip'
});

$("div.toolbar").html('<b>Custom tool bar! Text/images etc.</b>');
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/x4qqh4L5/) for code and demonstration.